# AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters not applied correctly to AudioMiX

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I am working on Application that combines the multiple videos along with background audio track. It also need to set different audio level for different videos.

Following is the code for AssetItem class &  AssetManager Class

```
 // AssetItem Class 
class AssetItem : NSObject {

var asset                   : Asset!
var assetEffect             : AssetEffectType!   // Enum 
var assetSceneType          : SceneType!         // Enum
var videoLength             : CMTime!
var animationLayer          : AnyObject?
var volumeOfVideoVoice      : Float = 0.0
var volumeOfBGMusic         : Float = 0.0

override init() {
    super.init()
   }
}

// AssetManager Class implementation 

class AssetManager{
 var assetList  = [AssetItem]()
 var composition                     : AVMutableComposition! = AVMutableComposition()
 var videoComposition                : AVMutableVideoComposition? = AVMutableVideoComposition()
 var audioMix                        : AVMutableAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()

 var transitionDuration              = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 600) // Default transitionDuration is 1 sec

var compositionTimeRanges           : [NSValue] = [NSValue]()

var passThroughTimeRangeValue       : [NSValue] = [NSValue]()
var transitionTimeRangeValue        : [NSValue] = [NSValue]()

var videoTracks                     = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()
var audioTracks                     = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()


// MARK: - Constructor
override init() {

    super.init()

    let compositionTrackA           = self.composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let compositionTrackB           = self.composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let compositionTrackAudioA      = self.composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let compositionTrackAudioB      = self.composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    self.videoTracks                = [compositionTrackA, compositionTrackB]
    self.audioTracks                = [compositionTrackAudioA, compositionTrackAudioB]

    }

    func buildCompositionTrack(forExport : Bool ){
       // This is the Method to Build Compositions
    }
}
```

FOllowing is the Method for BuildingCompositions

```
func buildCompositionTrack(forExport : Bool) {

    var cursorTIme = kCMTimeZero
    var transitionDurationForEffect = kCMTimeZero

    // Create a mutable composition instructions object
    var videoCompositionInstructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
    var audioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters]()

    let timeRanges = calculateTimeRangeForAssetLayer()
    self.passThroughTimeRangeValue = timeRanges.passThroughTimeRangeValue
    self.transitionTimeRangeValue = timeRanges.transitionTimeRangeValue

    let defaultMuteSoundTrackURL: NSURL = bundle.URLForResource("30sec", withExtension: "mp3")!
    let muteSoundTrackAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: defaultMuteSoundTrackURL, options: nil)
    let muteSoundTrack = muteSoundTrackAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

    for (index,assetItem) in self.assetsList.enumerate() {
        let trackIndex = index % 2

        let assetVideoTrack = assetItem.asset.movieAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, assetItem.videoLength)

        do {
            try self.videoTracks[trackIndex].insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: assetVideoTrack, atTime: cursorTime)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
        }
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: buildCompositionTracks for video with parameter index: %@ and VideoCounts: %@ error: %@", ["\(index)", "\(self.assetsList.count)", "\(error?.description)"])
            error = nil
        }

        if assetItem.asset.movieAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).count > 0 {
            let clipAudioTrack = assetItem.asset.movieAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

            do {
                try audioTracks[trackIndex].insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: clipAudioTrack,  atTime: cursorTime)
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
            }
        }else {
            do {
                try audioTracks[trackIndex].insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: muteSoundTrack, atTime: cursorTime)
            }catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
            }
        }

        // The end of this clip will overlap the start of the next by transitionDuration.
        // (Note: this arithmetic falls apart if timeRangeInAsset.duration < 2 * transitionDuration.)

        if assetItem.assetEffect == FLIXAssetEffectType.Default {

            transitionDurationForEffect = kCMTimeZero
            let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(cursorTime, assetItem.videoLength)
            self.compositionTimeRanges.append(NSValue(CMTimeRange: timeRange))
            cursorTime = CMTimeAdd(cursorTime, assetItem.videoLength)
        } else {
            transitionDurationForEffect = self.transitionDuration
            let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(cursorTime, CMTimeSubtract(assetItem.videoLength, transitionDurationForEffect))
            self.compositionTimeRanges.append(NSValue(CMTimeRange: timeRange))
            cursorTime = CMTimeAdd(cursorTime, assetItem.videoLength)
            cursorTime = CMTimeSubtract(cursorTime, transitionDurationForEffect)
        }

            videoCompositionInstructions.appendContentsOf(self.buildCompositionInstructions( index, assetItem : assetItem))

    }

    if self.project.hasProjectMusicTrack() && self.backgroundMusicTrack != nil {

        let url: NSURL = bundle.URLForResource("Music9", withExtension: "mp3")!
        bgMusicSound = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
        backgroundAudioTrack = bgMusicSound.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

        let compositionBackgroundTrack = self.composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

        let soundDuration =  CMTimeCompare(bgMusicSound.duration, self.composition.duration)

        if soundDuration == -1 {

             let bgMusicSoundTimeRange =  CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, bgMusicSound.duration)

             let noOftimes  = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.composition.duration) / CMTimeGetSeconds(bgMusicSound.duration))
             let remainingTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.composition.duration) % CMTimeGetSeconds(bgMusicSound.duration)

             var musicCursorTime = kCMTimeZero

             for _ in 0..<noOftimes {

                 do {
                    try compositionBackgroundTrack.insertTimeRange(bgMusicSoundTimeRange, ofTrack: backgroundAudioTrack, atTime: musicCursorTime)
                    } catch let error1 as NSError {
                       error = error1
                    }
                 musicCursorTime = CMTimeAdd(bgMusicSound.duration, musicCursorTime)
              }
         }

          let backgroundMusciMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: compositionBackgroundTrack)
          backgroundMusciMixInputParameters.trackID = compositionBackgroundTrack.trackID

          // setting up music levels for background music track.

           for index in 0 ..< Int(self.compositionTimeRanges.count) {

             let timeRange = self.compositionTimeRanges[index].CMTimeRangeValue
             let scene =  self.assetsList[index].assetSceneType

             let volumeOfBGMusic = self.assetsList[index].volumeOfBGMusic
             var nextvolumeOfBGMusic : Float = 0.0

              if let nextAsset = self.assetsList[safe: index + 1] {
                nextvolumeOfBGMusic =  nextAsset.volumeOfBGMusic
              }
              backgroundMusciMixInputParameters.setVolume(volumeOfBGMusic, atTime: timeRange.start)
        backgroundMusciMixInputParameters.setVolumeRampFromStartVolume(volumeOfBGMusic, toEndVolume: nextvolumeOfBGMusic, timeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(timeRange.end,CMTimeMake(2, 1)), CMTimeMake(2, 1)))
         }

      audioMixInputParameters.append(backgroundMusciMixInputParameters)

  } // End of If for ProjectMusic Check 


    for (index, assetItem) in self.assetsList.enumerate(){

        let trackIndex = index % 2

        let timeRange = self.compositionTimeRanges[index].CMTimeRangeValue
        let sceneType = assetItem.assetSceneType
        let volumnOfVideoMusic = assetItem.volumeOfVideoVoice

        let audioTrackParamater = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: self.audioTracks[trackIndex])

        audioTrackParamater.trackID = self.audioTracks[trackIndex].trackID
        audioTrackParamater.setVolume(0.0, atTime: kCMTimeZero )  // Statement 1
        audioTrackParamater.setVolume(volumnOfVideoMusic, atTime: timeRange.start) // Statement 2 
        audioTrackParamater.setVolume(0.0, atTime: timeRange.end) // statement 3
        audioMixInputParameters.append(audioTrackParamater)
    }

    self.audioMix.inputParameters = audioMixInputParameters
    self.composition.naturalSize    = self.videoRenderSize
    self.videoComposition!.instructions = videoCompositionInstructions
    self.videoComposition!.renderSize = self.videoRenderSize
    self.videoComposition!.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    self.videoComposition!.renderScale = 1.0        // This is a iPhone only option.

  }
```

In above code, Background Music Levels are set properly, but something is going wrong for audio levels of Video Tracks. I have added DebugView to help Debug Compositions, everything looks perfect in debug view, but other than Background Music Track, Audio of Video is no more audible. is there is something I am doing wrong?

If I remove Statement 1 from above code then its audible, but now they are all audible at level 1.0, and dont respect the levels set.

[image: DebugView of Compositions and Audio Tracks]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using a new AVAudioMixInputParameters object for each "clip" in the AVMutableCompositionTrack. This won't work: the new object will conflict with the previous object with the same track ID.

You should instead be using a single AVAudioMixInputParameters object for each AVMutableCompositionTrack, updating that object with each desired ramp value.

Comment: Dude, you were on the mark man. I feel like so stupid now. Yes, that was the issue. After your comment, I solved the issue in really 5 min. Are you based out of India? Would love to buy you beer man :-)